# MFC Network Admin Token

Tags: mfc, admin

I have a problem with PathFileExists("u:\networkpath\folder\file.csv"), when i execute my program with admin rights. It will always return false.

I tried to choose the CFileDialog, this will work fine. I think there is a problem with the user authorization on my server.

what must i do that PathFileExists autorized the admin user?
Is there a possibility to do this in my program?

Comment: Did you forget to use double backslash in your path: 
PathFileExists("u:\\networkpath\\folder\\file.csv")

Comment: What happens if you do an `fopen` with exactly the same argument that the one you pass to `PathFileExists`?

Comment: Or maybe there is an ANSI/UNICODE problem ?Anyway, show more code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem known since Vista and it is a direct consequence from UAC.

Here is an [explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/937624) and to get around the problem.

Read this [MSDN KB article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee844140%28v=WS.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to fix it.